# How to get values from an arraylist into an abstract class for comparison

Tags: java, arraylist

Example: I have a class 'model'

```
class Model {
  private ArrayList<Picture> pictures;
  public ArrayList<Picture> getPictureList() { return pictures; }
}
```

(i have methods that implement all this, this is just for example)

then i have

```
abstract class Picture{
  public boolean touches(Picture p) {}
}
```

I want this function to pull in values from the about arraylist for comparison against the argument "p" to see if the two pictures touch each other. 
I want to use something like this

```
public boolean touches(Picture p) {
     for (Picture picture : pictures) {
         //compare values
     }
}
```

How can i make it so that I can pull in values from the class 'model' into the abstract class picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I want to answer my own question, I am not sure if this will help anybody but I figured I would post it on here anyway. Basically I was approaching the problem incorrectly. The `Model` class creates an ArrayList of type `Picture` therefore, the values are already present in the `Picture` class variables. What I was trying to do was to send the entire ArrayList into the class when this was unnecessary. What I needed to do was call the method `overlaps()` from the `Model` class like this

```
for (Picture p1 : pictures) {
    for (Picture p2 : pictures) {
     p1.overlaps(p2);
     }
}
```

What this does is makes the each picture check itself against every other picture in the ArrayList and determine if they overlap. (assuming the overlaps function is implemented correctly) 
This is actually a very important idea to understand in Java and luckily I had a friend who could explain it

Answer (score 0):

You already have a `getPictureList()` method, so you can use it :

```
public boolean touches(Picture p) {
     for (Picture picture : modelInstance.getPictureList()) {
         //compare values
     }
}
```

However, a better implementation would be to remove `getPictureList()` and replace it with `Picture getPicture(int i)` and `int getNumberOfPictures()`. This way the user of your Model class won't get an access to the internal ArrayList (which would allow them to manipulate it directly).

Then your code would look like this :

```
public boolean touches(Picture p) {
     for (int i = 0; i < modelInstance.getNumberOfPictures(); i++) {
         Picture picture = modelInstance.getPicture(i);
         //compare values
     }
}
```

Another approach would be to implement an iterator, i.e. have `Model` implement the `Iterable<Picture>` interface.

Then your code would look like this :

```
public boolean touches(Picture p) {
     for (Picture picture : modelInstance) {
         //compare values
     }
}
```

Comment: ok so when I try this it says error getPictureList() is undefined for type Picture.

Comment: and by this, I mean the first approach.

Comment: @Chris getPictureList is defined in the Model class,  not the Picture class

Comment: Right, thats my real issue. I want to pull those values into the picture class. I'm sorry if I have conveyed this wrong, I appreciate the help